# PyQt QtWebkit: Visual analysis of the web page

Tags: qt, qt4, pyqt, pyqt4, qtwebkit

For my task I need to analyze visual structure of the web page. I am using QtWebkit via PyQt as its an easy to use implementation of Webkit and easily available on all distros.

QtWebkit provides QWebElement objects which has geometry property and I can use it to obtain the location and dimensions of each DOM node. However I also need to subtract the margin, border and padding from the geometry returned.

I am using the styleProperty() method of QWebElement to get the border and margin properties as:

```
documentElement.styleProperty('border-bottom', QWebElement.ComputedStyle)
```

But it return's empty string denoting absence of the style [method description here](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qwebelement.html#styleProperty). Please help me how can I get the border, margin and padding so that I can subtract those from the geometry returned by geometry() method.

Update 1: It happens that I can get the CascadedStyle for some elements but the ComputedStyle remains empty for all elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found with some hit and tries that border style is not used that much and I found other properties coming right.